# Convert Python dictionary into C like structure

Tags: python, c, dictionary, python-c-api

I am a newbie in Python and C and I would like to know how to put dictionary elements into a C like structure (struct).

For example, here is my structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int dim;
    float *Tab1;
    float *Tab2;
}  
Tableaux;
```

Here is my dictionary in Python:

```
Tableaux = {}
Tableaux["dim"]=None
Tableaux["Tab1"]=[]
Tableaux["Tab2"]=[]
```

Here is my interface function:

```
static PyObject* py_initTab(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    PyObject* dict;
    Tableaux Tab;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &dict))  
        return NULL;        

     Tab.Tab1=dict["Tab1"]; // How could I do something like that?      

     return Py_BuildValue("");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`PyDict_GetItem()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDict_GetItem) for that:

```
PyObject* pytab1 = PyDict_GetItemString(dict, "Tab1");
```

Since the result is a list, you can use [these](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html) calls to examine it

[This documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/concrete.html#numeric-objects) explains how to convert primitive types between C and Python.