# Convert python dict to a structure using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a structure like this:

```cpp
struct Person {
  std::string name;
  int age;
  std::string title;
  float income;
};
```

In the python side, I have a dict like this:

```py
person = { 'name':'Alex', 
           'age':36, 
           'title':'programmer', 
           'income':13435.40
          }
```

Now I want to convert the Python dict to the C++ program by using ctypes. There is a stupid way to do this task is that we can write 4 c-style functions to set these four elements independently. How can we do this task in a single function, which can solve different data type (string, int, float)?

Comment: What's `string`? If it's `std::string` it's a C++ program. There's no beast named C/C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python dictionary into C like structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217561/convert-python-dictionary-into-c-like-structure)

Comment: yes, it's std::string

Comment: Then you should have tagged appropriately. This requires **C++** expertise.

Answer (score 0):

`ctypes` can't handle C++ on its own.

[SWIG can](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Library.html#Library_stl_cpp_library) though this is equivalent to writing a C wrapper for the C++ code. It requires building native code.